# Coldfusion read HTTP post request from other server

Tags: http, post, coldfusion

I have a online form on a third-party server and the submission data is sent to my Coldfusion page using a standard HTTP POST request. I need to retrieve the form data in that .cfm page and insert to the database. I use requestcatcher.com and I can see the post request data format as below:

> POST /test HTTP/1.1 Host: mytest.requestcatcher.com Connection:
>   Keep-Alive Content-Length: 1198 Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=----------------------637248012629755039 Expect: 100-continue
>
> ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e_2113"
>
> My Name
>   ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="txtCity"
>
> My City
>   ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e_2123"
>
> District
>   ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e_2107"
>
> test@test.com
>   ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e_2128"
>
> 212-123-1234
>   ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e_2158"
>
> Maryland
>   ------------------------637248012629755039 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="e_2130"

I want to know how can I get the value of all the form-data.

Thanks

Comment: Just to add a little of code to Adrians answer: make a <cfdump var="#form#"> and you will see all the data saved in the form scope. Your data will be passed as form.name_of_a_datafield, for example form.e_2128 for email.

Answer (score 1):

Just dump the `form` scope to see all of the field names and values. You can then read that into the database. However, you should also setup an API key that the other server must send to you and you verify before processing data. Otherwise, anyone can send you form data and attack your database.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be in the `FORM` scope.

So you can access `txtCity` by doing `FORM.txtCity` for example.

It is also in `ARGUMENTS` scope if the form was submitting to a `cfc`. So you can do `ARGUMENTS.txtCity` as well in a CFC file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other valid answers, as well as accessing the `form` scope, or the `arguments` scope if the request was posted to a CFC, it is worth knowing that you can also use `getHTTPRequestData()` to access the raw request data. `getHTTPRequestData().content` in the case of a POST request body.

This can come in useful on rare occasions where the exact request data is needed, before it has been parsed into the `form` scope by CF. One real-world example is the Paypal IPN verification process where it is necessary to echo the form data back to their handler in exactly the same order, casing and encoding as the original POST body.

Some useful reading if you do need to use getHTTPRequestData() : https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2824-gethttprequestdata-may-break-your-request-in-coldfusion-but-gethttprequestdata-false-may-not.htm